# Change iFrame SRC and reload iFrame when database content changes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, iframe

I apologise if this has been covered however I couldn't find anything similar enough to help me.

I am basically looking to replace the src of 4 iFrames and reload them when content inside a database changes. I have 2 pages in this scenario. The first page is the controller page which updates the database with the changes. The second page is the view portal that has 4 iFrames in a quad split arrangement. The purpose of the page is to monitor specific sites and I would like to be able to update any one of the 4 iFrames remotely (say from an iPad).

I currently have my database setup. My table has 3 columns (id / name / url).
I've filled the table with 4 entries so far:
1 | frame1 | ht*p://www.google.com
2 | frame2 | ht*p://www.darkhorizons.com
3 | frame3 | ht*p://www.smh.com.au
4 | frame4 | ht*p://www.9to5mac.com

I would like my viewing portal page (Page2) to constantly check each entry in the db to see if it is different to what it is currently displaying. Something along the lines of: if db-frame1-url is not equal to iframe1.src then iframe1.src equals db-frame1-url. And so on...

I've build most of my site in PHP so far, however I've been told that an AJAX JQuery solution might be best for me here. I'm really not too sure as programming is not one of my strong suits.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

---

AJAX.PHP

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass","dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM frameContent");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
print_r(json_encode($row));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

---

OUTPUT.HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="../assets/scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "",
                cache: false,
                success: function(resp) {
                    //
                    try {
               json = $.parseJSON(resp);
            } catch (error) {
               json = null;
            }
            //
            if (json) {
                       console.dir(json);
                       $.each(json, function(key,val){
                          if ($("#"+val.name).attr("src") != val.src) {
                            $("#"+val.name).attr("src",val.src);
                          }
                       });
                    }

                }
            });
},6000);
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="frame1" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frame2" src="http://www.darkhorizons.com"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frame3" src="http://www.smh.com.au"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frame4" src="http://www.9to5mac.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make php page ajax.php where you will output mysql data:

```
print_r($result_of_query);
```

Now use jquery ajax to get the contents of this page.

Something like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "",
                cache: false,
                success: function(resp) {
                    //
                        console.dir(resp);
                        var frame1 = $("#frame1").attr("src");
                        console.dir(frame1);
                        if (frame1 != resp) {
                            $("#frame1").attr("src",resp);
                        }

                }
            });
},6000);
```

For multiple frames you can do following:

In the php, remove while loop and instead do this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Also let me know what output is there...

Now in ajax part:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "",
                cache: false,
                success: function(resp) {
                    //
                    try {
               json = $.parseJSON(resp);
            } catch (error) {
               json = null;
            }
            //
            if (json) {
                       console.dir(json);
                       $.each(json, function(key,val){
                          console.dir(val);
                          console.dir(val.name);
                          console.dir(val.url);
                          if ($("#"+val.name).attr("src") != val.url) {
                            console.dir("if worked!");
                            console.dir($("#"+val.name).attr("src"));
                            $("#"+val.name).attr("src",val.url);
                          }
                       });
                    }

                }
            });
},6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

A database change cannot update a page as in flow first client requests for the content and server responses it. For achieving your goal you need to use a `jquery or javascript timer` like other sites use to show the latest updated content (like cricket.yahoo.com for cricket scores).

After few seconds or minutes (whatever is your update frequency) you can send a **ajax request** to check the content change and if you find out there, then you can ask for the new src from your tables. Then simply change the **iframe src** using `javascript or jquery.`

Comment: Thanks for replying however this is exactly what I said I wanted to do in my description. I understand that I need a script to check the db and make the changes. Are you able to provide any other scripting examples rather than cricket.yahoo.com? Unfortunately I cannot really pull the code from there.